# How to call functions from new Angular in old AngularJS by ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I just started rewriting Old AngularJS to Angular 12 (client requirement) and I will do it piece by piece. Currently, I have a button that triggers a Dialog from the old AngularJS and I needs to trigger a rewritten Dialog (Angular Material) from the new Angular.

file.tpl.html

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="openDialog()">Open Dialog</button>
```

fileController.js

```
$scope.openDialog = function() { ... }
```

I'm wondering if I should create a simple component which button in the new angular and use it in the old one?

```
<new-app-open-dialog-btn></new-app-open-dialog-btn>
```

or... somehow provide a method from the service to open Dialog and use it in the AngulaJs controller? What are the approaches?

Comment: this is what the `downgradeComponent()` helper function is designed for.  https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/downgradeComponent

Comment: i saw this but this is solution for first approach (use component from new angular) but what about services from new angular? do you have idea how to provide method (new angular) witch I will be able to run from controller.js?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/downgradeInjectable